# Java bean validation Regex to get rid of CSV Injection

Tags: java, regex, security, bean-validation

In our java application, users can export data to excel files which are prone to [CSV Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSV_Injection). To avoid this vulnerability, I want to restrict the user input such as **=HYPERLINK(E3, F3)** if any parameter start with following chars:

```
Equals to ("=")
Plus ("+")
Minus ("-")
At ("@")
```

I tried some regexes:

```
^[^+=@-]

^((?![+=@-]).)*
```

But these are not working as expected in bean validation.

Comment: Can you please paste the code @Rajinder on how you resolved the issue. As I tried all the solutions provided in this link but still facing Vulnerability issue.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape the special characters in your regex like this:

```
String csvInjectionRegex = "^[^\\+\\=@\\-]";
```

The following characters are the ones that need to be escaped in a regex:

<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>

To escape them you either :

- use the backslash `"\\"`
- or use enclosed each special character in the both `\Q` and `\E` .Example:`("\\Q|\\E")`
- If you have any doubts  use the Pattern.quote(specialString):

`String csvInjectionRegex = "^[^"+Pattern.quote("+-=@")+"]";`

Comment: Thanks @arthur. It was silly mistake on my side. I just restarted server and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  if (value.matches("^[+=@-].*")) {
      //DO M
  }
```